# Error when attempting to upload shapefiles into Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When trying to import a new shapefile, I'm greeted with "Error: Unable to parse the specified file." I've imported hundreds of shapefiles previously so I have no idea why this error is just appearing now. I'm exporting the shapefiles from QGIS using a mac.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it worked when I renamed all the files with the same name as the .zip file.